# Using Landsat-Util?

Tags: python, landsat

I have installed landsat-util and tried to simply run the example code they provide in the documentation:

```
landsat download LC81050682014217LGN00
```

Which results in a syntax error:

```
  File "<tmp 1>", line 3
landsat download LC81050682014217LGN00
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here? I have also tried:

```
landsat.download [ID]
```

With the same results. I'm using Python 2.7 and Linux Mint 18 Sarah.

Comment: Run `landsat download [ID]` from a command prompt, not a python prompt (once landsat-util is installed correctly, and the landsat scripts/exes are on your PATH).

Comment: @Luke, i'm fairly new at Python. The second part of your answer 'scripts/exes on path', would you be able to explain that? Does this mean I have to tell command prompt where the package is located?

Answer (score 3):

Might be something wrong with your installation - this worked for me:

```
sudo pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade landsat-util
```

Comment: This got me further than before, and now I'm hitting this error:`Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    CRITICAL:root:Numpy and its headers are required to run setup(). Exiting.` I think I solved that issue with https://github.com/geowurster/gj2ascii/issues/10

Comment: Before you can run the command above, you must do `pip install numpy cython` because these two packages are needed to build one of landsat-util's dependencies (rasterio). (Related: installing non-wheel Python distributions with sudo is a security risk, it can run any Python code in the distribution's setup script as root.)

Comment: `ImportError: libgeos-3.4.2.so:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I did `sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev` and get the same error when running the initial code.

Comment: I assume you followed the installation procedure and did:                    `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-numpy python-scipy libgdal-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran libfreetype6-dev` ?